# What is the difference between nil in Objective-C and optional in case of swift which by default stores nil

Tags: objective-c, swift

In objective-c for example

```
NSString *test=nil;
```

In swift for example

```
var test: String? = nil
```

Comment: what do you think the differences are? what do you have a problem with? if this is really the extent of your question then go and read the official docs

Comment: Did you have a look at the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" reference? In particular the "Nullability and Optionals" chapter?

Answer (score 3):

Anything in Swift can be optional, not just object references. You can have an optional bool, with three possible values nil, false, and true. You can have an optional double. That is something that isn't available in Objective-C at all.

In Swift, object references come in two flavours: Optional and non-optional. Optionals can be nil or not nil. Non-optionals cannot be nil ever. In Objective-C, any object reference could be nil.

Answer (score 0):

The Swift type system will force you to deal with the optionality of `test`. You couldn't use it without unwrapping it first.

You couldn't call `test.lowercaseString`, because `test` is a `String?`, which could be `nil`. You'd have to unwrap it first:

```
if let test = test {
    print(test.lowercaseString)
}
else {
    //test was nil, handle error here
}
```

In Objective-C, `test` is just a variable, the type system has no clue about it being nil.

```
NSLog([test lowercaseString]) //Boom goes the dynamite.
```

You should read [the language guide section on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330).

Comment: Calling a method on `NULL` in Objective-C just does nothing.  It doesn't crash.  It works like `test?.lowerCaseString` does in Swift.

Comment: In Objective-C, if you forget to wire up your `IBOutlets` for instance, nothing happens.  In Swift, you get a crash trying to unwrap `nil`.  The Swift way is much easier to find and debug.

Comment: @vacawama You're right, but it's still undesirable behaviour